# Why does this Mean Value Theorem proof state that a function is both the sum and difference of two other functions?

Tags: calculus

The following picture depicts an early portion of the Mean Value Theorem proof using Rolles Theorem.

[image: rollestheoremapplication]

I am confused as to why on statement 4) we have that

$h(x)=f(x)-f(a)-\frac {f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} (x-a)$

And then later down we have the following statement:

1. The function h is continuous on [a,b] because it is the $sum$ of f and a first-degree polynomial both of which are continous

Why does it state sum if it is a difference? My interpretation is that they mean the following:

$h(x)=f(x)-f(a)+(-\frac {f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} (x-a))$

That is, - as +-. However, this seems off, they must have a good reason to say sum, so I know I am misunderstanding something here. Also, since a functions graph must pass the horizontal line test h(x) is not the function, it is just the y  value on a function h which is not displayed, correct?

Answer (score 3):

They mean sum in a broad sense, where a minus is taken as a "plus opposite". If you write $3+4-5+7-3$, you call that a sum.

By the way, the statement is rigorous as they say the "sum of … and a first degree polynomial", which can have coefficients of any sign.